# Not able to connect to Database with oci8

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I have below configuration to connect to DB through spring-hibernate.
I have commons-dbcp-1.4.jar,commons-pool-1.6.jar,classes12.jar,ojdbc14.jar

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="true">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:oci8:@DBSchemaName"/>
            <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
            <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
            <property name="maxIdle" value="1"/>        
            <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
            <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="30"/>
            <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>        
    </bean>
```

I am using dbcp for connection pooling.I also tried changing the url to

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:oci8:/@DBSchemaName"/>
```

Still no success.
I am getting below error

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:84)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me to understand what is the issue?

Comment: Can any one help me please...I am stuck here !!!

Comment: Does anyone has any idea how to solve this issue??